# Why does my menu not resize and scale properly when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having issues with my resizing / scaling header. I want it to scale as I scroll to include the logo in the upper left and the menu in the upper right, while the logo and menu remain centered at the top.

```js
  $(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll >= 1) {
        $(".stickyjs").addClass('sticky');
      } else {
        $(".stickyjs").removeClass("sticky");
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Museo Sans for Dell";
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: solid #eeeeee 1px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
header h1#logo {
  width: 647px;
  height: 351px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav#menu {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
header.sticky {
  height: 75px;
}
header.sticky h1#logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8px;
  left: 10%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
header.sticky nav#menu {
  width: 700px;
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: solid #eeeeee 1px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
footer div#itsbroke {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
footer div#isocompliance {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
footer.sticky {
  height: 50px;
}
footer.sticky div#itsbroke {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
footer.sticky div#isocompliance {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
header img,
footer img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
header span,
footer span {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.upper,
.confirm,
.select,
.verify {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.lower {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a name="#TOP" class="TOP"></a>

<header class="stickyjs">

  <h1 id="logo">
   <a href="#TOP"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/tA93HGZ.png" /><span>Two Minute Drill</span></a>
  </h1>

  <nav id="menu">
    <a href="#CONFIRM">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iVaqRXi.jpg" /><span>Confirm Parts Needed</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#SELECT">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rMUChKc.jpg" /><span>Select Parts Identified</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#VERIFY">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pkKndfS.jpg" /><span>Verify Parts Selected</span>
    </a>
  </nav>

</header>

<footer class="stickyjs">

  <div id="itsbroke">
  </div>

  <div id="isocompliance">
  </div>

</footer>

<div class="upper"></div>

<!-------------------------->
<!-- CONFIRM PARTS NEEDED -->
<!-------------------------->

<div>

  <a name="CONFIRM"></a>
  <h3 class="confirm" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">Confirm Parts Needed</h3>

  <p></p>

  <p><a href="#TOP">Back to Top</a>
  </p>
  <hr>

  <h3 style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;"></h3>

  <p>2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue nulla, fermentum sit amet euismod et, dapibus a justo. Phasellus eu lacus gravida, scelerisque nisi luctus, dignissim arcu. Vestibulum ultricies arcu vitae nisi faucibus cursus.
    Pellentesque eleifend neque nec sapien tincidunt hendrerit. Mauris lacus felis, ultrices eget nisi in, laoreet tincidunt arcu. Phasellus ac odio sed nisi lacinia vulputate. Sed eleifend et odio id venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
    dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce accumsan nisl tincidunt, facilisis purus vitae, pretium mi. Integer bibendum, est et condimentum elementum, lectus enim rhoncus eros, ac sodales elit felis at lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce
    dignissim mattis eros vel venenatis. Donec vitae nisi est.</p>

  <p><a href="#TOP">Back to Top</a>
  </p>
  <hr>

  <h3 style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;"></h3>

  <p>3Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue nulla, fermentum sit amet euismod et, dapibus a justo. Phasellus eu lacus gravida, scelerisque nisi luctus, dignissim arcu. Vestibulum ultricies arcu vitae nisi faucibus cursus.
    Pellentesque eleifend neque nec sapien tincidunt hendrerit. Mauris lacus felis, ultrices eget nisi in, laoreet tincidunt arcu. Phasellus ac odio sed nisi lacinia vulputate. Sed eleifend et odio id venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
    dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce accumsan nisl tincidunt, facilisis purus vitae, pretium mi. Integer bibendum, est et condimentum elementum, lectus enim rhoncus eros, ac sodales elit felis at lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce
    dignissim mattis eros vel venenatis. Donec vitae nisi est.</p>

  <p><a href="#TOP">Back to Top</a>
  </p>
  <hr>

</div>

<!----------------------------->
<!-- SELECT PARTS IDENTIFIED -->
<!----------------------------->

<div>

  <a name="SELECT"></a>
  <h3 class="select" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">Select Parts Identified</h3>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue nulla, fermentum sit amet euismod et, dapibus a justo. Phasellus eu lacus gravida, scelerisque nisi luctus, dignissim arcu. Vestibulum ultricies arcu vitae nisi faucibus cursus.
    Pellentesque eleifend neque nec sapien tincidunt hendrerit. Mauris lacus felis, ultrices eget nisi in, laoreet tincidunt arcu. Phasellus ac odio sed nisi lacinia vulputate. Sed eleifend et odio id venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
    dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce accumsan nisl tincidunt, facilisis purus vitae, pretium mi. Integer bibendum, est et condimentum elementum, lectus enim rhoncus eros, ac sodales elit felis at lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce
    dignissim mattis eros vel venenatis. Donec vitae nisi est.</p>

  <p><a href="#TOP">Back to Top</a>
  </p>
  <hr>

  <h3 style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;"></h3>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue nulla, fermentum sit amet euismod et, dapibus a justo. Phasellus eu lacus gravida, scelerisque nisi luctus, dignissim arcu. Vestibulum ultricies arcu vitae nisi faucibus cursus.
    Pellentesque eleifend neque nec sapien tincidunt hendrerit. Mauris lacus felis, ultrices eget nisi in, laoreet tincidunt arcu. Phasellus ac odio sed nisi lacinia vulputate. Sed eleifend et odio id venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
    dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce accumsan nisl tincidunt, facilisis purus vitae, pretium mi. Integer bibendum, est et condimentum elementum, lectus enim rhoncus eros, ac sodales elit felis at lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce
    dignissim mattis eros vel venenatis. Donec vitae nisi est.</p>

  <p><a href="#TOP">Back to Top</a>
  </p>
  <hr>

  <h3 style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;"></h3>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue nulla, fermentum sit amet euismod et, dapibus a justo. Phasellus eu lacus gravida, scelerisque nisi luctus, dignissim arcu. Vestibulum ultricies arcu vitae nisi faucibus cursus.
    Pellentesque eleifend neque nec sapien tincidunt hendrerit. Mauris lacus felis, ultrices eget nisi in, laoreet tincidunt arcu. Phasellus ac odio sed nisi lacinia vulputate. Sed eleifend et odio id venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
    dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce accumsan nisl tincidunt, facilisis purus vitae, pretium mi. Integer bibendum, est et condimentum elementum, lectus enim rhoncus eros, ac sodales elit felis at lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce
    dignissim mattis eros vel venenatis. Donec vitae nisi est.</p>

  <p><a href="#TOP">Back to Top</a>
  </p>
  <hr>

</div>

<!---------------------------->
<!-- VERIFY PARTS SELECTEDE -->
<!---------------------------->

<div>

  <a name="VERIFY"></a>
  <h3 class="verify" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">Verify Parts Selected</h3>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue nulla, fermentum sit amet euismod et, dapibus a justo. Phasellus eu lacus gravida, scelerisque nisi luctus, dignissim arcu. Vestibulum ultricies arcu vitae nisi faucibus cursus.
    Pellentesque eleifend neque nec sapien tincidunt hendrerit. Mauris lacus felis, ultrices eget nisi in, laoreet tincidunt arcu. Phasellus ac odio sed nisi lacinia vulputate. Sed eleifend et odio id venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
    dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce accumsan nisl tincidunt, facilisis purus vitae, pretium mi. Integer bibendum, est et condimentum elementum, lectus enim rhoncus eros, ac sodales elit felis at lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce
    dignissim mattis eros vel venenatis. Donec vitae nisi est.</p>

  <p><a href="#TOP">Back to Top</a>
  </p>
  <hr>

  <h3 style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;"></h3>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue nulla, fermentum sit amet euismod et, dapibus a justo. Phasellus eu lacus gravida, scelerisque nisi luctus, dignissim arcu. Vestibulum ultricies arcu vitae nisi faucibus cursus.
    Pellentesque eleifend neque nec sapien tincidunt hendrerit. Mauris lacus felis, ultrices eget nisi in, laoreet tincidunt arcu. Phasellus ac odio sed nisi lacinia vulputate. Sed eleifend et odio id venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
    dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce accumsan nisl tincidunt, facilisis purus vitae, pretium mi. Integer bibendum, est et condimentum elementum, lectus enim rhoncus eros, ac sodales elit felis at lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce
    dignissim mattis eros vel venenatis. Donec vitae nisi est.</p>

  <p><a href="#TOP">Back to Top</a>
  </p>
  <hr>

  <h3 style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;"></h3>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue nulla, fermentum sit amet euismod et, dapibus a justo. Phasellus eu lacus gravida, scelerisque nisi luctus, dignissim arcu. Vestibulum ultricies arcu vitae nisi faucibus cursus.
    Pellentesque eleifend neque nec sapien tincidunt hendrerit. Mauris lacus felis, ultrices eget nisi in, laoreet tincidunt arcu. Phasellus ac odio sed nisi lacinia vulputate. Sed eleifend et odio id venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
    dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce accumsan nisl tincidunt, facilisis purus vitae, pretium mi. Integer bibendum, est et condimentum elementum, lectus enim rhoncus eros, ac sodales elit felis at lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce
    dignissim mattis eros vel venenatis. Donec vitae nisi est.</p>

  <p><a href="#TOP">Back to Top</a>
  </p>

</div>

<div class="lower"></div>
```

Comment: Looking at the snippet, it looks like it is doing what you described it should do. It will only work on desktop currently, though.

Comment: This entire question was formatted horribly. It is my first time using Stack Overflow. When I look at the code in Google Chrome on my local machine, the logo works fine, but the menu images do not resize or reposition themselves during scrolling, and the styling is the EXACT same between the logo and menu, except for some changes to top positions. Let me clarify, the menu items do reposition themselves, but they don't resize properly, and the top is cut off.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it appears to be working just fine. Is there any errors in your developer console? Maybe I'm not understanding how it is supposed to look; can you post an image?

Comment: @AdamMazzarella The "Confirm", "Select", and "Verify" are cut off.

Comment: It looks the same for me in Chrome and IE. The top half of the menu images are cut off, and they are not resizing like the logo, even though I do not have hard-coded width and height on the images and the CSS includes max-width: 100% and height: auto;. I've stripped out everything I could to find the issue, and it just doesn't stand out to me.

http://i.imgur.com/3PB3GaA.jpg

Comment: I've tried to clean up my code a little bit, using Tidy, and to point out one more issue with this menu—without a margin: -50px; on nav#menu, the images are not inline like they were in my picture above.

Comment: @Jeb The snippet is broken now

Comment: @AdamMazzarella Sorry, I forgot to pull the Imgur links over. That's been fixed.